# unable to give the bullets as li under li

Tags: html, wordpress

i m using an  bootstrap span class as span 2 span 4 and etc....my problem is that i wnat to give the same look to my li under the li as the parent li means bullets filled with black color but unable to do so .....please help me out guys.

Here is my code for li and ul:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
<li class="span2"><span style="color: #e15b1f;">DESIGNER/FASHION HOUSES</span>
<ul>
<li>ASHIMA & LEENA SINGH Delhi</li>
<li>JATTIN KOCHHAR Delhi</li>
<li>JJ VALAYA Gurgaon</li>
<li>MANAV GANGWANI Delhi</li>
<li>MANDIRA WIRK Delhi</li>
<li>MONISHA BAJAJ and CO.Delhi</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="span2"><span style="color: #e15b1f;">RETAIL 
ORGANISATIONS</span>
<ul>
<li>EBONY 
Delhi</li>
<li>SHOPPERS STOP 
Mumbai</li>
<li>PANTALOONS 
Mumbai</li>
<li>LIFESTYLE 
Delhi</li>
<li>TOMMY HILFIGER 
Bangalore</li>
<li>NIKE 
Bangalore</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="span2"><span style="color: #e15b1f;">DOMESTIC 
COMPANIES</span>
<ul>
<li>INTERTEK 
Gurgaon</li>
<li>WECA 
Gurgaon</li>
<li>BIBA APPARELS 
Delhi</li>
<li>SEWA 
Delhi</li>
<li>PROVOGUE 
Mumbai</li>
<li>BOMBAY DYEING 
Mumbai</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="span2"><span style="color: #e15b1f;">OVERSEAS 
COMPANIES</span>
<ul>
<li>CARREFOUR INDIA 
United Kingdom </li>
<li>COLBY INTERNATIONAL 
New York</li>
<li>GAP INTERNATIONAL 
USA</li>
<li>LI AND FUNG 
Hong Kong</li>
<li>POETICGEM UK</li>
<li>JILL STUART 
New York</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply adding

```css
li {
    list-style-type: disc !important;
}
```

To your style sheets/head style tag should do the trick.

Comment: I would offer a demo, but jsfiddle doesn't wish to cooperate.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to apply `list-style-type: disc;` to the level of LI's you wish to have a bullet.

**http://jsfiddle.net/aab2p/2/**

My example shows all LI's under the red headings with bullets:

```
ul > li > ul > li {
    list-style-type: disc !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as Daedalus's answer, but in HTML file.
`<li style="list-style-type: disc;">ASHIMA & LEENA SINGH Delhi</li>`

Comment: CSS styling should be kept to CSS stylesheets, where possible, as in the other answers given.

Answer (score 1):

As no-one else has, I shall offer an answer that actually uses the already in-place classes. Place this code in your CSS stylesheet:

```
li.span2 ul li {
    list-style: disc;
}

//OR

ul.thumbnails > li.span2 > ul > li {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

You may wish to apply `!important` to it to override existing styling, as in Daedalus' or Adam's answer, but this time you won't affect any other nested lists in your site.

Answer (score 1):

The following is sufficient for overriding the *browser default*s (which use `circle` for inner lists) so that list items have solid (`disc`) list bullets:

```
ul li, ul li li { list-style-type: disc; }
```

If this is not sufficient for overriding the settings in some bootstrap code that you are using, then you need to analyze that code and set up a CSS with a more specific selector. Using e.g. Firebug in Firefox you can see which CSS rules are applied to each element.